# Where is best place to set control extended styles in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a simple MFC MDI application, where there is main CFormView, in which there is CListCtrl control. I want to set its extended styles like below:

```
m_listctrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER|LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
```

Question is where should I place this initialisation code? I tried to put it in CMyFormView constructor, but I realised that my CListCtrl control is created in CMyFormView::DoDataExchange(), by:

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_INVENTORY, m_listctrl);
```

So constructor is before DoDataExchange() and will cause Assert failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `SetExtendedStyle()` in the `OnInitDialog()` override (`WM_INITDIALOG` handler).

Comment: Yes, I do similar thing. I put it in CMyFormView::OnInitialUpdate(), like below: CFormView::OnInitialUpdate(); m_listctrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER|LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);

I am just wondering if I am right and if there is better place. Thanks.

Comment: As AAT said that you should call SetExtendedStyle() in the OnInitDialog(), if you are not programmatically creating your CListCtrl because all the controls on your GUI are created before OnInitDialog() is called. And it is the best place to set the initial state of your controls like if you want to disable some of them or hide others and etc.

Comment: I found an issue with this, though fixed here: http://kb.roguewave.com/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=587